# THIS ... IS ... FORTRESS!

Tags: code-golf

Fortress was a language being developed by the Sun Programming Language Research Group (R.I.P. Fortress) that had a unique property to it, it was possible to render ("Fortify") programs in different font-styles (i.e. blackboard bold, bold, italics, roman, etc. ). The goal is to represent a one-char Fortress variable in HTML markup.

Here's how the fortification of one-char variables worked (simplified/modified from documentation for code-golfing purposes):

- If the variable is a repeated capital (i.e. `ZZ`), it becomes formatted in blackboard bold (`ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ`)
- If the variable is preceded by an underscore, the variable is rendered in roman font (left alone)
- If the variable is followed by an underscore, the variable is rendered in bold font (`<b>`v`</b>`)
- If the variable is neither preceded nor followed by an underscore, the variable is rendered in italic font (`<i>`v`</i>`)
- The codepoints of the blackboard bolds are: :1D538, :1D539,  `ℂ`:2102, :1D53B, :1D53C, :1D53D, :1D53E, `ℍ`:210D, :1D540, :1D541, :1D542, :1D543, :1D544, `ℕ`:2115, :1D546, `ℙ`:2119, `ℚ`:211A, `ℝ`:211D, :1D54A, :1D54B, :1D54C, :1D54D, :1D54E, :1D54F, :1D550, `ℤ`:2124. These count as **one byte each** in your program (if your language of choice can handle these characters at all)

Input will be either a repeated ASCII capital, or a single ASCII letter with either no underscore, a leading underscore, or a trailing underscore (AKA `_a_` will not be an input). This is code-golf so lowest byte count wins!

Test cases:

```
a => <i>a</i>
BB => 
c_ => <b>c</b>
_d => d
E => <i>E</i>
G_ => <b>G</b>
_H => H
ZZ => ℤ
```

Links: [Specification](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/samth/fortress-spec.pdf), [Direct download of version 0.1 alpha](http://web.archive.org/web/20070715233437/http://fortress.sunsource.net/files/documents/81/140/fortress_168.zip).

Reference implementation (This would be in Fortress, but Fortress doesn't like most of the doublestruck characters, so this implementation is in D):

```d
dstring fortify(string arg) {
    import std.string, std.conv;

    alias D = to!dstring; //Convert to a string that accepts the unicode needed
    dstring BB = "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ"d; //blackboard bold capitals
    string UC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //normal ASCII capitals

    if(arg.length == 1)
        return D("<i>" ~ arg ~ "</i>");
    if(arg[0] == a[1])
        return D(BB[UC.indexOf(arg[0])]);
    if(arg[0] == '_')
        return D(arg[1]);
    return D("<b>" ~ arg[0] ~ "</b>");
}
```

Comment: I forgot to remove them, sandbox link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13383/55550

Comment: Are the only uppercase variables the double repeated ones, and are the only lowercase ones the other three?

Comment: Uppercase can be normal, italic, and bold. Lowercase can not be doublestruck.

Comment: `_____` won't be input.

Comment: Oh... So it's not a string of characters we're converting, just a single one?

Comment: If you're referring to the Fortress variable, then yes.

Comment: Why is the reference implementation not in Fortress? I have been scammed!

Comment: Why not `a` => `` `BB` => `` `c_` => `` `_d` => `` `E` => `` `G_` => `` `_H` => `` or something?

Comment: Too much unicode (I might make a separate challenge with more of Fortress's rendering included, and unicode)

Comment: Well ... fortress didn't like ``, otherwise it would've been in Fortress.

Comment: Neim is probably the only language here that has `` in its codepage... the thing is, it's rule #150.5 compliant (is awful with strings)

Comment: I modified the question so the doublestruck characters only count as 1 byte each.

Comment: In what way do they "count" as one byte each? If my language has not got them in its code-page I must insert them, is it any code required to do so, or are you favouring languages that can have Unicode strings within their code?

Comment: Any usage of them within the code counts as one byte.

Comment: Can i output `&#120120` instead of ``?

Comment: No, you may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 73 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sub>Turns out that not being able to use the BBB letters in the code is quite expensive.</sub>

```
5ŀ”i
“Ðñṡ’Dẋ@€“¡ḞḄ’ż“¿¿Æ€¢¬µ‘+⁽ø³F⁸ṪO¤+ị¥Ọ
Ṫ
Ḣ5ŀ”b
;j“<>/”ṃ@“¢ʠf’
i”_+LµĿ
```

A full program taking one argument and printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/0aMOjhrmZXI8a5hyecHjjw50LHzXMdHm4q9vhUdMaoOChhQ93zHu4owUoenQPiL//0P7DbUC5Q4sOrTm09VHDDO1HjXsP7zi02e1R446HO1f5H1qi/XB396GlD3f3cAH5XA93LIJYksRlnQU0wcZOH8h5uLPZAWTcolML0oBmc2UCxeK1fQ5tPbL/////zs7/AQ)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/0aMOjhrmZXI8a5hyecHjjw50LHzXMdHm4q9vhUdMaoOChhQ93zHu4owUoenQPiL//0P7DbUC5Q4sOrTm09VHDDO1HjXsP7zi02e1R446HO1f5H1qi/XB396GlD3f3cAH5XA93LIJYksRlnQU0wcZOH8h5uLPZAWTcolML0oBmc2UCxeK1fQ5tPbL//8PdWw63A62I/P8/kcvJiSs5nis@hcuVyx1Ie3A5O3N5eHD5@XEFBHAFBnIFBXFFRf0HAA).

#### How?

The main entry point is the last line of code ("Main link").

```
5ŀ”i - Link 1: list of characters, s (length 1 & no underscore)
  ”i - literal character 'i'
5ŀ   - call link 5 as a dyad with s on the left and 'i' on the right

“Ðñṡ’Dẋ@€“¡ḞḄ’ż“¿¿Æ€¢¬µ‘+⁽ø³F⁸ṪO¤+ị¥Ọ - Link 2: list of characters, s (length 2 & no underscore)
“Ðñṡ’                                 - base 250 literal              1007245
     D                                - to decimal list               [1,0,0,7,2,4,5]
         “¡ḞḄ’                        - base 250 literal              111673
      ẋ@€                             - repeat with reversed @rguments for €ach -> [[111673],[],[],[111673,111673,111673,111673,111673,111673,111673],[111673,111673],[111673,111673,111673,111673],[111673,111673,111673,111673,111673]]
               “¿¿Æ€¢¬µ‘              - code page index list          [11,11,13,12,1,7,9]
              ż                       - zip together                  [[111673,11],[11],[13],[[111673,111673,111673,111673,111673,111673,111673],12],[[111673,111673],1],[[111673,111673,111673,111673],7],[[111673,111673,111673,111673,111673],9]]
                         ⁽ø³          - base 250 literal              8382
                        +             - addition (vectorises)         [[120055,8393],[8393],[8395],[[120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055],8394],[[120055,120055],8383],[[120055,120055,120055,120055],8389],[[120055,120055,120055,120055,120055],8391]]
                            F         - flatten                       [120055,8393,8393,8395,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,8394,120055,120055,8383,120055,120055,120055,120055,8389,120055,120055,120055,120055,120055,8391]
                                ¤     - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:                                                                                    ^
                             ⁸        -   chain's left argument, s  e.g.    "CC"                                                                                 |
                              Ṫ       -   tail (last character)             'C'                                                                                  |
                               O      -   cast to ordinal                   67                                                                                   |
                                   ¥  - last two links as a dyad:                                                                                                |
                                  ị   -   index into (1-indexed & modular)  8383 (this is at index 67%26=15 -----------------------------------------------------+ )
                                 +    -   add the ordinal                   8450
                                    Ọ - convert from ordinal to character   'ℂ'

Ṫ - Link 3: list of characters, s (length 2 & underscore at index 1)
Ṫ - tail (get the first character

Ḣ5ŀ”b - Link 4: list of characters, s (length 2 & underscore at index 2)
Ḣ     - head s (the non-_ character)
   ”b - literal character 'b'
 5ŀ   - call link 5 as a dyad with the non-_ character on the left and 'b' on the right

;j“<>/”ṃ@“¢ʠf’ - Link 5, wrap in a tag: element, tagName      e.g. 'a', 'i'
;              - concatenate the element with the tagName          "ai"
  “<>/”        - literal list of characters                        "<>/"
 j             - join                                              "a<>/i"
         “¢ʠf’ - base 250 literal                                  166603
       ṃ@      - base decompression with reversed @rguments
               -   "a<>/i" is 5 long, so 166603 is converted to
               -   base 5 [2,0,3,1,2,4,0,3] with digits "a<>/i"    "<i>a</i>"

i”_+LµĿ - Main link: list of characters, s (as specified only):
 ”_     - literal '_'
i       - index of '_' in s (1-indexed; 0 if not found)
    L   - length of s
   +    - addition
     µĿ - call link with that number as a monad with argument s
        - implicit print
```

Comment: Fails on input `ZZ`.

Comment: Oh, is that in a different place in Unicode? Bizarre choice they made.

Comment: Yeah, doublestruck `C` `H` `N` `P` `Q` `R` and `Z` are at different places in unicode.

Comment: (Read the fifth bullet point)

Comment: LOL, it's fun to see Jelly flop like that!

Comment: Careful what you say, Dennis will show up and post a twelve byter for it :p

Comment: I haven't seen Dennis answer on one of my questions yet, I'm hoping for it!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.6, <s>159</s> <s>131</s> 128 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Zacharý*

*3 bytes saved thanks to @VаlueInk*

*28 bytes saved thanks to @Rod*

```python
lambda s:len(s)<2and f"<i>{s}</i>"or s[0]==s[1]and"ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ"[ord(s[0])-65]or[f"<b>{s[0]}</b>",s[1]][s[0]=='_']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5LasMwFEXnXcVDE9ng0B/tINgeBEK7B1UYu46pIZWDlYFLKfQjOuh/UA8a8CyLSGnTxWgF2YF7RQTnPnQfQmd2Nb@o1GFfUERn/TS9zPKU9HA6UZ72w4NU5VSwsIyv9U24W8asqkmLPRlFWuxLbNmm@1yBb2vuMX7AL1iDP2teN117C@4A1u0DMNa0GI/WfFmzsKbD5Qk8gxfg3ryBd/BhzZKJqs4996k/OD6SVS0glEEIDZyymAXORYqtF0@47AtoNlQqEjzlAfHRyOV54jLJXY5dnGyLUx7I4Q7hzOpSzb0GZRRjVXiN7/f/)

Comment: `len(s)<2 and`=>`len(s)<2and`

Comment: Look at the new edit to the post, ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ count as 1 byte each.

Comment: [128 bytes by moving your first condition to the end.](https://tio.run/##JY5LasMwFEXnXcVDE9ng0B/tINgeBEK7B1UYu46pIZWDlYFLKfQjOuh/UA8a8CyLSGnTxWgF2YF7RQTnPnQfQmd2Nb@o1GFfUERn/TS9zPKU9HA6UZ72w4NU5VSwsIyv9U24W8asqkmLPRlFWuxLbNmm@1yBb2vuMX7AL1iDP2teN117C@4A1u0DMNa0GI/WfFmzsKbD5Qk8gxfg3ryBd/BhzZKJqs4996k/OD6SVS0glEEIDZyymAXORYqtF0@47AtoNlQqEjzlAfHRyOV54jLJXY5dnGyLUx7I4Q7hzOpSzb0GZRRjVXiN7/f/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>104</s> <s>106</s> 105+1 = <s>105</s> <s>107</s> 106 "bytes"

Probably works even better in Retina. Uses `-p` flag.

-1 byte from Zacharý.

```ruby
gsub /^.$/,'<i>\0</i>'
gsub(/(.)\1/){$1.tr"A-Z","ℂ-ℍ-ℕℙℚℝ-ℤ"}
gsub /(.)_/,'<b>\1</b>'
gsub ?_,''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElBP05PRV9H3SbTLsbARj/TTp0LJKyhr6GnGWOor1mtYqhXUqTkqBulpKP0Ye6UHUC881FLE5DarQsk9j1q6f0wd2oDkD215VHLVCDV9qhl5qOWWY9a5gI5XSCJCY9alijVckHsAxocD7IwyS7G0EY/CWqhgn28jrr6//@JXE5OXMnxXPEpXK5c7kDagys8/F9@QUlmfl7xf90CAA)

Comment: You forgot `JJ`, `KK`, `LL`, `TT`, `UU`, `VV` and `WW`.!! (Which is probably why `MM` gives `ℙ`)

Comment: @Zacharý fixed.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by making `-` `-`.

Comment: You didn't update your TIO link for the 1-byte saving. Also, this fails badly in Retina which uses UTF-16 and so can't translate a single A-Y to a two-char16_t blackbold character.

Comment: @Neil oops. Fixed link.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 97 chars

```
([a,b])=>a==b?[...'ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ'][a.charCodeAt()-65]:b?b=='_'?a.bold():b:a.italics()
```

Why a language have methods like [`String.prototype.italics`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/italics) and [`String.prototype.bold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold)?

Thanks to Neil, save 9 bytes, use `[...s]` instead of `s.match(/./u)`.

Comment: Is this ES6, or ES7?

Comment: `u` flag in RegExp is ES6 feature. `String.prototype.italics` and `String.prototype.bold` are just some legacy features.

Comment: I knew it was ES6 ... 'cause fat arrows.

Comment: change "ES6" to "ES6 or ES7" in the above comment.

Comment: `[...'ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ']` should save you some bytes.